# Running phpinfo() on 7.2.4 returns the version as 7.2.1?

Tags: php, apache, curl

I'm having problems enabling cURL on my Apache server, so when I was looking into it and trying to see what was wrong, I noticed this in my httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/PHP/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

This is normal and the file exists, but when I run phpinfo() and visit the page, it says at the top:

```
PHP Version 7.2.1
```

I'm certain I installed 7.2.4 as it wasn't too long ago, so why would it be saying 7.2.1 on the info page?

Thanks o/

Comment: `php7apache2_4.dll` means that it's the PHP7 module for Apache 2.4, not that it's PHP 7.2.4

Comment: If phpinfo() says it's version 7.2.1, then it's version 7.2.1

Comment: [PHP 7.2.4 was released on March 29, 2018](http://php.net/archive/2018.php#id2018-03-29-2). What is the last modified time of `httpd.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

most likely, you already had 7.2.1 installed, and your attempt at installing 7.2.4 failed, but in your failed attempt at installing 7.2.4, you did not break the existing 7.2.1 installation.